# error with stat_compare_means and multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I would like to label my boxplots with pvalues.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(df_annot,aes(x=Insect,y=index,fill=Fungi))+geom_boxplot(alpha=0.8)+
  geom_point(aes(fill=Fungi),size = 3, shape = 21,position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.02,jitter.height = 0))+
  facet_wrap(~Location,scales="free" )+
  stat_compare_means(aes(group="Insect"))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend("M. robertii")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels= c("I+","I-","soil alone"))+
  ylab(index_name)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14)) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14),
        legend.title=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14))
```

Here is the error message that I'm getting:

> Warning messages:
>   1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'p'.
>   2: Computation failed in `stat_compare_means()`: argument "x" is missing, with no default
>   3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'p'.
>   4: Computation failed in `stat_compare_means()`: argument "x" is missing, with no default

I've tried moving around the `aes()` from the main ggplot call to the boxplot call.  I've tried different `inherit.aes` in the `stat_compare_means()`.
I've tried first subsetting the root section and making them separately , but the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

here is my data:

```
> dput(df_annot)
structure(list(Location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Root", "Rhizospheric Soil"
), class = "factor"), Bean = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bean", "No bean"), class = "factor"), 
Fungi = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("M+", "M-"), class = "factor"), Insect = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Insect", 
"NI"), class = "factor"), index = c(2.90952191983974, 3.19997588762484, 
2.96753469534499, 2.93030877512644, 2.72220793003196, 3.09008037591454, 
2.63687890737919, 2.73583925812843, 3.06766793411045, 3.26431040286099, 
3.03361194852963, 2.9181623054061)), row.names = c("S-B1", 
"S-B2", "S-B3", "S-BF-1", "S-BF-2", "S-BF-3", "S-BFi-1", "S-BFi-2", 
"S-BFi-3", "S-Bi-1", "S-Bi-2", "S-Bi-3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Consider to include sample data in your question to make your problem reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

A possible and easy fix to your error maybe to use the exact variable name (i.e. remove the double quotes from the variable name) rather that the quoted variable name (i.e. character) in the stat_compare_means (), so the function should look like this:

```
stat_compare_means(aes(group=Insect))
```

A working example using ggboxplot() is as follows:

```
library(ggpubr)

boxplot <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", add = "jitter",
                             color = "supp", group="supp", palette = "jco", legend.title="Supplier")
boxplot <- boxplot + stat_compare_means(aes(group=supp), label = "p.signif", method="wilcox.test", hide.ns=T, paired=F)

print(bxp.legend)
```

[image]
There is a warning message for the above example, but I do not know how improve the code to remove the warning message:

```
`cols` is now required.
Please use `cols = c(p)`
```